# Cascading binary replication to logical postgres

Tags: postgresql, replication, master-slave-replication

Im using Postgres 10, and I was wondering if its possible to cascade a logical replication from a binary slave replica? I am looking to have databases with the same data but indexed in a different way is this possible and makes sense?

[image]

Comment: [According to the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/logical-replication-publication.html) you can only create a publisher on the master database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks didn't noticed that detail.